# Newbie-ish error: cp: omitting directory

Tags: linux, shell, find

Pulling my hair as I'm stuck with a basic error without understanding why:

```
find . -type f -exec cp del {} \;
```

We're in a "test" directory, in which I created one "del" subdirectory. The "test" directory contains a variety of files of various types.

The result is a series of lines (same number as the number of files present in the directory from where the command is ran) with:

```
cp: omitting directory `del'
```

Possibly useful details follow.

- Debian Wheezy, standard shell interface.
- As a prelude to more complex exclusion and exec patterns I wanted to start with this fundamental test... and had this.
- I think I excluded the "del" directory with "type -f", so it's not as if I was asking Linux to move a directory within itself.
- There are no other directories or subdirectories.
- Permissions: everything belongs to the current user.
- I made variations for the "cp del" part, putting it in simple or double quotes, or using ./del, no difference.

I also tried with -R

```
find . -type f -name '*script1*' -exec cp -R ./del {} \;
```

That gave:

```
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory `./script1' with directory `./del'
```

Same with `-r`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is to copy some files found by find command to the del directory, then you can do it like this:

```
find . -type f | xargs cp -T del/
```

Or like this:

```
find . -type f -exec cp {} del \;
```

Comment: Dangit! {} before the target dir!! Thank you Vrs :)

Comment: @EcchiOli yes, that's easy. Just think of '{}' as a wildcard for any file returned by the find command. An excerpt from find's man page: 'If the string ``{}'' appears anywhere in the utility name or the arguments it is replaced by the pathname of the current file.'